# Getting this error "System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object" due to response body , pl help me if anyone knows

Tags: apex, json, httpresponse

We are getting below Json format as response and storing into Respbody variable .

But when we are deserializing that we are getting below error:

`error : System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object`

```
[
    {
        "validOrder": 1,
        "orderno": "W2424591",
        "statusId": "4",
        "statusDesc": "Order Despatched",
        "connote": "POU281160",
        "carrierCode": "ST",
        "carrierDesc": "Star Track",
        "carrierService": "NORMAL",
        "carrierTrackPage": "https://startrack.com.au/"
    },
    {
        "validOrder": 1,
        "orderno": "W2424998",
        "statusId": "4",
        "statusDesc": "Order Despatched",
        "connote": "PSG002080537",
        "carrierCode": "TE",
        "carrierDesc": "TNT Road Express",
        "carrierService": "NORMAL",
        "carrierTrackPage": "http://www.tntexpress.com.au/interaction/trackntrace.aspx"
    }
]
```

Code:

```
fromJSON n = (fromJSON)JSON.deserialize(respBody, fromJSON.class);

public class fromJSON {
        
    public String validOrder;   
    public String orderno;  
    public String statusId; 
    public String statusDesc;
    public String connote;  
    public String carrierCode;  
    public String carrierDesc;  
    public String carrierService;
    public String carrierTrackPage;
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your deserialization to be a list, since this is the equivalent of an array which is what you have in your JSON:

```
List<fromJSON> n = (List<fromJSON>)JSON.deserialize(respBody, List<fromJSON>.class);
```

Comment: Thank you Phil for the update it's working now
but if i try to add deserialized "n" values into object  fields getting error like n.validOrder not exists, pl let me know way to add 
 List<fromJSON> n = (List<fromJSON>)JSON.deserialize(respBody, List<fromJSON>.class);
Sample_Order_Copy__c soc = new Sample_Order_Copy__c();
                soc.ValidOrder__c = n.validOrder;

Comment: Just do `n[0].validOrder` if there is only ever one entry in the array. Better to iterate the array using `for (fromJSON entry : n) {` and in here use `entry.validOder` etc.

Comment: Thank so much Phil , it is working